# Who rules Gallifrey after season 9 finale? [Spoilers]

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord, gallifrey

During the season 9 finale "Hell bent" the Doctor

> overthrows the Lord President Rassilon in what amounts to a military coup and becomes the new Lord President. This state of affairs is short lived however as the Doctor breaks a bunch of laws to save Clara and flees Gallifrey again.

My question is who is in charge now?

> The most likely candidates are probably the General or Ohila, High Priestess of the Sisterhood of Karn.

Not sure if this info exists yet, but hoping Moffat might have said something.

Comment: **We don't know.**

Comment: Also, it's not the first time The Doctor is given that position and flees Gallifrey again.

Comment: @rand al'thor Do you think asking if anyone has Steven Moffat's phone number would be off topic?

Answer (score 2):

I think “right now”, the Doctor rules Gallifrey. But, if you know the story of Hell Bent, the Doctor has forgotten his near past, which may create an absence of a ruler in Gallifrey — or may not, 'cause Gallifrey is situated in nearly the end of time.

- Even if the Doctor get backs his memory, I don't think he will accept the post of “President of Gallifrey” and most chances are he will hand this post to the General.
- Even if he does, that wouldn't matter much after all — the General mostly looks after everything.
- While, if the Doctor is absent from Gallifrey, I think the General will take the decisions in the name of the President.
- If there is democratic voting or something like that and the High Council decides to have a new President, that most probably will not be anyone from the Sisterhood of Karn, cause they are neither Gallifreyan nor  a part of the High Council of Timelords.

So most probably, chances are that the Doctor retains the post or the General will be elected as the new President. Moreover, no one actually knows what will happen in season 10, these are all just predictions.

Comment: The Doctor didn't forget his immediate past, he only forgot one detail about his current incarnation (not saying what because spoilers). He remembers being named president, since he included it in his story to the waitress in the diner.

Comment: He remembers being president, but as a story. He also remembers Clara also, but only in the story. He remembered everything, but not as a reality.  It's a little hard to explain, but look he didn't believe any of it till he got into his TARDIS.

Answer (score 2):

There's **probably a power vacuum**, and most likely **the General is effectively ruling Gallifrey**, after having backed the Doctor against Rassilon. He should call elections, but we don't know the state of Gallifreyan politics after a long and deadly war and a possibly even longer, and despotic, presidency of Rassilon. So it may take a while.

When the Fouth Doctor ran from the Presidency, the first time, after being elected (*The Deadly Assassin*), one of the Cardinals of the High Council (Borusa, I think) assumed the government without deposing him. But the Doctor expelled not only the previous President but the whole High Council, that is, the whole government. There's likely no one else ready to take charge of the government.